# Accessing web services in iPhone using SOAP without method names?

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ios4

I am trying to access a webservice from my server using this tutorial [consume web services](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209/1954).. i have been successful in accessing the web service and retrieving a string from it. but in most of the tutorials i have come across we need to give the method names in the web service thru the SOAP actions.. **Is there any way in which we can even retrieve the methods that are present in the web service first within our application and then access it using those methods**,, so the web service will be more flexible then and we can add more methods later??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WSDL from service and generate proxy. WSDL contains service methods list. Check [this](http://cocoadev.com/forums/discussion/42/writing-a-web-service-client-in-objective-c-with-cocoa-hows/p1)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that springs to mind is to hit the WSDL definition, and search through it for the messages and data types you want.